# Add string to python list -> json object

Tags: python, json

I have the list below:

```
rainbow = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow' ,'orange']
```

and I would like the output to be a JSON object like so:

```
{
  "rainbow":[
    {
        "color": "green"
    },
    {
        "color": "red"
    },
    {
        "color": "blue"
    },
    {
        "color": "yellow"
    }
    {
        "color": "orange"
    }
]}
```

any ideas? I've tried a couple of things and been struggling to find a solution.

```
import json
import itertools

rainbow = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow' ,'orange']

d = dict((k,'color') for k in rainbow)

skittles = json.dumps(d)

print skittles

{"blue": "color", "orange": "color", "green": "color", "yellow": "color", "red": "color"}
```

Comment: Maybe you're close to the solution? Post your code.

Comment: whoops, my bad...just added

Answer (score 2):

Your solution creates a flat dictionary with wrong key-value order. You should try something like:

```
{'rainbow': [{'color': color} for color in rainbow]}
```

This creates a 'rainbow' key, with a list of dictionaries as its value (created using list comprehension).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this something like that:

```
import json
json.dumps({"rainbow": [{"color": color} for color in rainbow]})
```

Comment: Marcin, thank you for assisting as well.  I went with Maroun's answer above.